# PHP Content-Disposition: attachment / Content-Type

Tags: php, header, attachment

just a little question (PHP):
I'm using

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
readfile('test.pdf');
```

to download a file under another filename.
But in every script-example of this, there was "header('Content-type: application/pdf');" before this 2 lines in the code.
I deletet the content-type-line and it still works fine.
Do i need the missing line, when i just want to change the name of the downloaded file?
Because therre are many filetypes, that can be downloaded in my website and so i would have to read the content-type before...

Thanks in advance for a short but understandable answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need it.

If you don't supply it, then PHP will default to outputting `Content-Type: text/html` which will cause problems (at the very least) for browsers that only handle inline content (such as Mobile Safari).

Comment: Ah damn, you're right. My browser seems to have cached something so it worked out for a while without the content-type. Is there any way to get a universal-Attribute or an easy way to read the attribute from a file and paste it there automatically?