# TCPDF $pdf->Output('out.pdf', 'I'); gone bad

Tags: tcpdf

I’m trying to learn TCPDF but I’m stuck on a strange problem. This is my code based on the example.

```
require_once('../tcpdf.php');
ob_start();

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF("P","mm","A4",true,"UTF-8",false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('User');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
// print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
// helvetica or times to reduce file size.
//~ $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

// Add a page
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->AddPage();

// set text shadow effect
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));

$html = "ASD";
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');   
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output('prova.pdf', 'I');`
```

When the PHP reaches the Output command, something has gone wrong. It doesn’t open the PDF page in the browser, but instead prints a strange output, like if I open a PDF file with a text editor.

Here I used `writeHTML()`, but it’s the same with `Image()`: I’ve already tried it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Content-Disposition` header.

See this other thread: [PHP Content-Disposition: attachment / Content-Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770517/php-content-disposition-attachment-content-type)

Answer (score 0):

I tested the things that you did, and it’s working for me. I think perhaps if you download TCPDF again and replace your current folder with the new copy.

Also, when including images, make sure that your image type is `.jpg`.

```
$html = 'ASD
<img src="project path/images/image.jpg"/>
';
```